# Setting up Wordpress site for AMP - SEO implications

Tags: seo, wordpress, duplicate-content, negative-seo, amp

This is fairly new and I have been reading up on AMP implantation. There is a plugin that sets up AMP pages for WordPress.

My concern is duplicate content since there will be a new set of pages with `/amp/` at the end.

Has anyone setup AMP on a WordPress site before and what are some negative SEO implications?

Answer (score 1):

I did. AMP plugin with Yoast SEO is best solution that is out there.

https://yoast.com/setting-up-wordpress-for-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages/

The AMP plugin by Automattic uses a default set of metadata, which is sometimes, if you’re using Yoast SEO, not the most optimal metadata.

There's a great plugin for that **[here.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/glue-for-yoast-seo-amp/)**

Set that up, and you are good to go.